# Сокеты Windows - Поведение при переполнении буфера

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2

Параметр `SO_RCVBUF` задает размер буфера сокета для приема данных. Что произойдёт, когда принимающая сторона долго не вызывает `recv` и буфер полностью заполняется?

Comment: Используется TCP